# Trying to read in tables stored in HDF5 stores in Julia as a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, julia, hdf5

I was trying to read in a table stored in a HDF5 store and read it in as a Dataframe in Julia. I'm finding some of the documentation confusing when it comes to using the HDF5 package in Julia and I've been wondering if there is something like the pandas equivalent:

```
table_data = pd.read_hdf('filepath', key='group')
```

My code goes like this:

```
using HDF5

file_input = "filepath/file.h5"

fileop = "r"

table_name = "group"

h5_store = h5read(file_input, fileop)

table_data = read(h5_store, table_name)

close(h5_store)
```

I've been wondering if its something that I've been doing incorrectly and would appreciate any guidance on this

Answer (score 5):

use `h5open` instead of `h5read` to fix your code:

```
h5_store = h5open(file_input, fileop)
```

However you can use `h5read` that by default uses read-only access to hdf5 file:

```
using HDF5

file_input = "filepath/file.h5"

table_name = "table"

table_data = h5read(file_input, table_name)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks again, but even though the syntax is correct I'm getting an error message of 'Not yet supported'. I probably should have noted that the tables in the h5 store are pytables. Are there compatibility issues with pulling pytable objects stored within an h5 store in Julia?

Comment: If the pytable contains variable-length datatype you'll get the error. The tagged version of HDF5.jl (0.7.3) checks for a string in the HDF5Dataset and if it finds one it throws "Not yet supported" error.

Comment: Try to checkout master version `Pkg.checkout("HDF5")` and give it a try...